# parseInt() doesnot converting each array element of an array into an integer

Tags: javascript, php, json, facebook-graph-api

```
$query = "SELECT id FROM server";
$result = mysql_query($query);


while($row =mysql_fetch_array($result))

{
    $dServer = $row['id'];

?>

<script>
  var dServer = <?php echo $dServer; ?>;
  document.write(dServer);
  var d=parseInt("dServer") + "<br>";
  document.write(d);
</script>

}
```

here everything is okk,`"dServer"` prints the `"id"`,but just `parseInt()` not converting `"id"` into integer. Could anyone please explain what is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are inputting a string to `parseInt()`. Instead use as follows.

```
var d=parseInt(dServer) + "<br>";
```

Again why you are using javascript to print the same. You could use PHP to do print the value of id to the document.

Comment: Okay fine, but can you please paste a value printed as id?

Comment: it prints "828683" as an string

Comment: In that case, you could get it as integer if you do `parseInt(dServer)`. Whats the error you are getting or whats the output?

Comment: I need an integer to use it as an facebook id, the error is "d does not resolve to a valid user ID", when i just put  "828683" then it works good. I learned that "d" parameter must be an integer.

Comment: Can you please paste the facebook api script also?

Comment: No, don't quote variables. `FB.ui({ method:'feed',from:d,to:r , message: ''},` should work.

Comment: @Newer And upvote and accepted answer is another one. Anyway good to hear its working. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Dont use as a String :

```
var d = parseInt(dServer) + "<br>";
```

Comment: but its not converting into an integer

Comment: yeah beacause we are concating a string "<br>" to get int remove "<br>"

Comment: what is the value in dServer

Comment: an integer as an string. Example "828683" it is a string, I cant add 1 with it.

Comment: Try this on console : var d = parseInt("828683") + 1;

Comment: I need an integer to use it as an facebook id, the error is "d does not resolve to a valid user ID", when i just put "828683" then it works good. I learned that "d" parameter must be an integer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT id FROM server";
$result = mysql_query($query);

while($row =mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $dServer = $row['id'];
?>

<script>
  var dServer = <?php echo $dServer; ?>;
  document.write(dServer);
  var d=parseInt(dServer);
  document.write("<br>"+d);
</script>

<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: sorry friend, actually its just a sample, I have used php tag in my code. Thank you.